# Word for "Having had considerable thought put into [x]"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am trying to describe a plan that has "had considerable thought put into it" with a single word. Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting more thought into it.

Comment: @HotLicks I've been thinking for about 1/2 hour, thanks. (Nice joke, if it was one `;)`)

Comment: Wasn't exactly a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can say that the plan is *[incisive](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=incisive%20define)*, which, as formally defined by *Google*, stands for:

> adj. - *(of a person or mental process) intelligently analytical and clear-thinking.*

Or *[judicious](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=judicious%20define)* (from *Google*'s first result as well)

> adj.- *having, showing, or done with good judgment or sense.*

Comment: @conor no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I would have said "a thoughtful plan."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As you should know, StackExchange expects answers which *explain*, including your reasoning, examples, and any appropriate references. As the question seeks a *single* word, this submission might have been better as a comment than as an answer. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help),